# The file can not be opened, downloaded or is corrupted when forcing its download

Tags: php

This is how my webhosting scheme looks like:

[image]

This is the code I'm having problems with, trying to force a file to be downloaded:

```
$fetch_file = $set_query->fetch_assoc();
$file = "../library/".$fetch_file["file_name"];
if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file)) {
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {       
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); 
}
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"'.basename($file).'\"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Connection: close');
ob_end_flush();
ob_end_clean();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

The download dialog actually pops up but I get an error from my browser saying that it was unable to read, and as a result, unable to open or download.

I tried to put `ob_end_flush()` and `ob_end_clean()` before the headers but it didn't work out. I don't know why the download dialog properly shows the file to download but says it can't be read nor opened.

I managed to fix that by using:

```
// digital_lub/JKAJSD831.pdf
$file = UPLOAD_PATH.$fetch_file["file_name"];
```

The dialog opens and downloads the file now but it won't open locally, saying it's corrupted. When I open it as text, it contains the HTML of my page.

My download page is requested by being included in `index.php` via an `.htaccess` url rewrite. This is `index.php`:

```
<?
require_once("constructor.php");
$smarty->display("page_index");
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {

    $page = htmlspecialchars($_GET["page"]);
    $setPageFile = "module/".$page.".php";

    if (file_exists($setPageFile)) {
        include($setPageFile);
    } else {
        $smarty->assign("alert", array(1, "Żądany moduł nie jest obsługiwany."));
    }
} else {
    Header("Location: login");
}
$smarty->display("page_footer");
?>
```

Comment: place your file(s) inside your public_html somewhere. If that works, then you'll know what to go after; *the path*. I doubt you can use a relative path for root folders.

Comment: Honestly? I wouldn't know. That's the first time I have to go outside root folder with attachments.

Comment: I tend to think so, yes. Try `$file = "/library/"` or if your server requires something like `$file = "/var/usr/library/"`

Comment: Even something like `$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/library/';` try one of those.

Comment: Neither works. With all these solutions, file cannot be found at all. I get my custom error after file_exists($file) && is_file($file);

Comment: It doesn't work when it's in public_html/ sub-folder too.

Comment: what's the value of `$file = "../library/".$fetch_file["file_name"];` as I think it'd still open up the dialog even if the db query returned "" judging by your code

Comment: The dialog opens and downloads the file now ($file = UPLOAD_PATH.$fetch_file["file_name"]; value is = digital_lub/JKAJSD831.pdf), but it won't open, saying it's corrupted.

Comment: @Sates what is the file size of the one that gets corrupted? we also need to know what the query is for `$fetch_file = $set_query->fetch_assoc();` and the db schema for it.

Comment: Fred, there's no need to post that. File gets uploaded properly, I can open it manually when uploaded but can't open whenever I try to download it. file_exists() and is_file() are working fine, they see the file. Download dialog displays fetched file name and extension propery, the path is fine. The problem is, the file is corrupted upon opening.

Comment: @Sates Remove `readfile($file);`, change the filename header to `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'.txt"');`, download a file, open it and tell us what is written inside.

Comment: Inside is a HTML code of my page, it happens to every *.png and *.pdf file I upload. By the way, the value of $file is "digital_lib/4A8T7DG2W9MY1FI_1444319771.png". It's accessible manually.

Comment: @Sates Pretty much what I expected. Can you post the whole page code ?

Comment: although now it's just for testing purposes: http://pastebin.com/1a4Ew5Xk. I cannot post the whole page code, it's split into parts that are connected with includes. This is index.php: http://pastebin.com/C6kVsn0s

Comment: @Sates So basically `index.php` is always called and includes whatever *page* you've selected, including the download one. It's always: *show header, show page, show footer*, right ?

Comment: Yes, that's my .htaccess:

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
AddHandler php5.3-fastcgi php
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$              index.php?page=$1         [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$           index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2      [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$        index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2&module=$3    [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$     index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2&module=$3&submodule=$4 [QSA,L]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91841/discussion-between-sates-and-spenibus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially your problem is that you send more data than just your file. Since your page is actually included in another page, which displays some header before reaching any kind of download logic, that extra HTML becomes part of your downloaded file, corrupting it.

There are two steps to avoid this:

1. Remove [`ob_end_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php), as it would still flush the buffer to the client and you clearly don't want that, and leave only [`ob_end_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php), which will destroy whatever is in the buffer.
2. In your top most document `index.php`, which includes the subpages (such as your download page), put [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) at the very beginning to capture absolutely all output and add [`ob_end_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) at the very end to output your content.

This creates 2 execution paths:

- Save output, generate page, flush output thus displaying the page.
- Save output, trigger download, destroy output, send file data, exit early.

This ensures that only your file's data is sent to the client.

This is a basic example of this logic:

- `index.php`:

  ```
  <?php
  ob_start();
  echo '__HEADER__';
  require('page.php');
  echo '__FOOTER__';
  ob_end_flush();
  ?>
  ```
- `page.php`:

  ```
  <?php
  ob_end_clean();
  readfile('test.txt');
  exit();
  ?>
  ```
- `test.txt`:

  ```
  __TEST__
  ```

This should only output `__TEST__`.

Comment: Thank you very, very much. I feel so ashamed that I didn't think this way. Never have I had more sincere gratitude towards anybody here. Thank you again for solving my issue. It means a lot to me and further developement of my project.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and you didn't closed your if bracket ;), i am sure it is not the reason, you missed it here but when i tried it, i am able to download file.
File was png, you can manually try for a file with php script, if it's not then it can be your server permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the file **extension/type**, browser will not guess it :) 
Here, a **PHP** script that you can customize if your server can handle more type of files.

```
<?php
    //---------------------------------------------------------
    //----------------- MIME TYPE DEFINITION ------------------
    //---------------------------------------------------------
    $mimeType = array() ;

    #[text]
    $mimeType["txt"]    = "text/plain" ;
    $mimeType["sql"]    = "text/plain" ;
    $mimeType["htm"]    = "text/html" ;
    $mimeType["html"]   = "text/html" ;
    $mimeType["css"]    = "text/css" ;

    #[image]
    $mimeType["png"]    = "image/png" ;
    $mimeType["gif"]    = "image/gif" ;
    $mimeType["jpg"]    = "image/jpeg" ;
    $mimeType["jpeg"]   = "image/jpeg" ;
    $mimeType["bmp"]    = "image/bmp" ;
    $mimeType["tif"]    = "image/tiff" ;

    #[archives]
    $mimeType["bz2"]    = "application/x-bzip" ;
    $mimeType["gz"]     = "application/x-gzip" ;
    $mimeType["tar"]    = "application/x-tar";
    $mimeType["zip"]    = "application/zip";

    #[audio]
    $mimeType["aif"]    = "audio/aiff";
    $mimeType["aiff"]   = "audio/aiff";
    $mimeType["mid"]    = "audio/mid" ;
    $mimeType["midi"]   = "audio/mid";
    $mimeType["mp3"]    = "audio/mpeg" ;
    $mimeType["ogg"]    = "audio/ogg" ;
    $mimeType["wav"]    = "audio/wav" ;
    $mimeType["wma"]    = "audio/x-ms-wma" ;

    #[video]
    $mimeType["asf"]    = "video/x-ms-asf" ;
    $mimeType["asx"]    = "video/x-ms-asf" ;
    $mimeType["avi"]    = "video/avi" ;
    $mimeType["mpg"]    = "video/mpeg" ;
    $mimeType["mpeg"]   = "video/mpeg" ;
    $mimeType["wmv"]    = "video/x-ms-wmv" ;
    $mimeType["wmx"]    = "video/x-ms-wmx" ;

    #[xml]
    $mimeType["xml"]    = "text/xml" ;
    $mimeType["xsl"]    = "text/xsl" ;

    #[microsoft]
    $mimeType["doc"]    = "application/msword" ;
    $mimeType["docx"]   = "application/msword" ;
    $mimeType["rtf"]    = "application/msword" ;
    $mimeType["xls"]    = "application/excel" ;
    $mimeType["xlsm"]   = "application/excel" ;
    $mimeType["xlt"]    = "application/excel" ;
    $mimeType["xlsx"]   = "application/excel" ;
    $mimeType["pps"]    = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" ;
    $mimeType["ppt"]    = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" ;

    #[adobe]
    $mimeType["pdf"]    = "application/pdf" ;
    $mimeType["ai"]     = "application/postscript" ;
    $mimeType["eps"]    = "application/postscript" ;
    $mimeType["psd"]    = "image/psd" ;

    #[macromedia]
    $mimeType["swf"]    = "application/x-shockwave-flash" ;

    #[real]
    $mimeType["ra"]     = "audio/vnd.rn-realaudio" ;
    $mimeType["ram"]    = "audio/x-pn-realaudio" ;
    $mimeType["rm"]     = "application/vnd.rn-realmedia" ;
    $mimeType["rv"]     = "video/vnd.rn-realvideo" ;

    #[other]
    $mimeType["exe"]    = "application/x-msdownload" ;
    $mimeType["pls"]    = "audio/scpls" ;
    $mimeType["m3u"]    = "audio/x-mpegurl" ;
    // <--

    //---------------------------------------------------------
    //----------- INITIALIZING DOWNLOAD PROCESS ---------------
    //---------------------------------------------------------
    $fileToUpload; // TODO! $_REQUEST['PATH/TO/FILE/FILENAME.FILEEXTENSION'] ??
    if (strlen(trim($file_to_upload_s)) == 0) {
        print '[ERROR] file name is empty' ;
        return ;
    }
    $fileExtension = pathinfo($fileToUpload, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
    $fileExtension = strtolower($fileExtension);
    if (strlen(trim($fileExtension)) == 0) {
        print '[ERROR] file extension is not mentioned' ;
        return ;
    }

    if(array_key_exists($fileExtension, $mimeType ) === FALSE ) {
        print '[ERROR] server does not support this file extension [' . $fileExtension . '], configuration is missing' ;
        return;
    } 

    //---------------------------------------------------------
    //------------- STARTING DOWNLOAD PROCESS -----------------
    //---------------------------------------------------------
    header('Content-Type: ' . $mimeType[$fileExtension]);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileToUpload . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileToUpload));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Cache-Control: private');
    header('Pragma: private');
    header('Expires: Mon, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT');
    readfile($fileToUpload);
?>
```

Comment: That's what header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); is for.